# Need SQL solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Problem:

```
Num  String      Score
1    Overall      5
1    Comments    Good
2    Overall      4
2    Comments    Fine
3    Overall      5
3    Comments    Fine
```

I want results like this.

```
Num    String    Score    Comments
1       Overall   5        Good
2       Overall   4        Fine
3       Overall   5        Fine
```

Can anyone help me with SQL Code for this

Comment: Hello, Sam!  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please provide some additional information:  You database schema; the query you're working on that isn't working; what your query returns, or what error it encounters.  Thanks!

Comment: Also include your attempts to solve this yourself.  SO isn't a code-writing service, but we are happy to help with incomplete solutions.

Comment: This is a classic `PIVOT` problem. Take a look at the documentation, and give it a shot. If you're still having trouble come back, tell us what you tried, and we'll try to give you more help. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Think this database really needs some refactoring. The solution suggested by @sgeddes works, but to pick our specific rows based on certain strings is poor database design.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select num, 
    'Overall' as string,
    max(case when string = 'Overall' then score end) as score
    max(case when string = 'Comments' then score end) as comments
from yourtable
group by num
```